# How to override settings in Semantic UI v1

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm using a sidebar in Semantic UI v1.1.2 but don't want it to apply a dimmer to the rest of the page when the sidebar is active.
I can see this is controlled by settings.dimPage, but I don't know how to override the default true value when building my dist files, or when hooking up my sidebar?

I'm activating it on the page like this:
`$('.sideMenu').sidebar('attach events', '.menu.button');`

It looks like I should be able to pass something like `{'dimPage': false}` in as a parameter, but I don't know how to combine it with the above 'attach events'...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just figured this out myself by using the kitchensink code example.

Should be something like this for your example:

```
$('.sideMenu').sidebar('setting', { dimPage: false });
$('.sideMenu').sidebar('attach events', '.menu.button');
```